# How can I take max id into a TextView?

Tags: java, c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I'm using sqlite with xamarin. I want to give some kind of query and take `max(id)` to a `TextView`. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
 string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "student.db3");
 var db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
 db.CreateTable<ExtrasPreviewClass>();

 TextView txtExtrasID = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtExtrasID);
        txtExtrasID.Text = Convert.ToString(mitems[position].id);

 var data = db.Table<ExtrasPreviewClass>(); //Call Table  

 txtExtrasID.Text = Convert.ToString(db.Query<ExtrasPreviewClass>("select max(_id) from ExtrasPreviewClass "));
```

But my result is something `system.collection.list1(ExtrasPreviewClass)`. How can I manage take `max(id)` into a `TextView`?

This is my class:

```
class ExtrasPreviewClass
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_Id")]

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string ExtrasName { get; set; }
    public string ExtrasCheckBox { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the `ToString()` representation of the object.

If you want to show something else, you may want to override the method in your `ExtrasPreviewClass`:

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"Id: {id}, Name {ExtrasName}, CheckBox {ExtrasCheckBox}";
}
```

Or you could simply change your last line from:

```cs
txtExtrasID.Text = Convert.ToString(db.Query<ExtrasPreviewClass>("select max(_id) from ExtrasPreviewClass "));
```

to:

```cs
var extras = db.Query<ExtrasPreviewClass>("select max(_id) from ExtrasPreviewClass ");
txtExtrasId.Text = extras.id; // or whatever you want to display
```

Comment: Id(in extras.id) it does not exist in my list. Should i use something else?